# Convert date to epoch time using AWK in linux

Tags: linux, excel, unix, awk

I have a comma-separated file, with the first column as a date of the format 01/31/2010
that I want to change into epoch time, such that the file "file.csv":

```
 01/30/2010,1,"hi"
 01/31/2010,3,"bye"
```

will change into "output.csv":

```
 1264809600,1,"hi"
 1264896000,3,"bye"
```

I know the command line date -d "01/30/2010" +%s will work, but only on a single date, and I need to feed it into a table, so, is there a way to use awk with some func():

```
cat file.csv | awk -F, 'print func($1)","$2","$3}'
```

Since I don't really care how I do this, alternatively, how would I change a date in excel into epoch, when the string is mm/dd/yyyy...

Comment: You should indicate your timezone. It is PST, right?

Comment: Do you not have control over the generation of the file? Would you be able to generate the file with epoch time instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
TZ=PST awk -F, '{split($1,date,"/");
                 $1=mktime(date[3] " " date[1] " " date[2] " " "00 00 00");
                 print}'
```

Or, invoking `date`:

```
TZ=PST awk -F, '{ OFS = FS;
                  command="date -d" $1 " +%s";
                  command | getline $1;
                  close(command);
                  print}'
```

Comment: the second answer seems nicer, however, in case when the first field doesn't change in following input lines (records) only the first line of the sequence gets the first field converted, the next converted line is the one that has the first field different than previous lines... why is it so?

Comment: @pms: `getline` checks the command/file it is accessing. If it's an already opened one, it reads the next input line from there. So, you need to `close` the command. Nice catch, I never noticed that about `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

On excel, say a1 has 1/30/2010.  then have `=(A1-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400` somewhere and then change number format to be General

Alternatively, I dont know awk, but with python, (fairly recent version is needed for .total_seconds())

```
import datetime as DT
f = [
'01/30/2010,1,"hi"',
'01/31/2010,3,"bye"',
]
e0 = DT.date(1970,1,1)
for line in f:
    mm,dd,yyyy=[int(x) for x in line[:2],line[3:5],line[6:10]]
    e=int((DT.date(yyyy,mm,dd)-e0).total_seconds())
    print str(e) + line[10:]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "2016-01-31 23:47:27" | awk -F, '{ OFS = FS;command="date -d " "\"" $1 "\""  " +%s";command | getline $1;close(command);print}'
```

We need to pass double quotes because we need to execute below:

```
date -d"2016-01-31 23:47:27" +%s
```

Comment: are you giving an answer or asking a questions?

Comment: This is the same answer as given by ninjalj , difference is it is inline.You will get If you will try to run above commands.

Comment: echo "2016-01-31 23:47:27" | awk -F, '{ OFS = FS; command="date -d\""$1" "$2"\" +%s"; command | getline; close(command); print}'      works just as well with less apostrophes.