# Add to CSV a timestamp column based on other columns (using bash)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I need to read a CSV file (*list.csv*) like this:

```
0;John Doe;2001;03;24
1;Jane Doe;1985;12;05
2;Mr. White;2018;06;01
3;Jake White;2017;11;20
...
```

and add a column (doesn't matter where I put it) with a Unix timestamp based on the year/month/day being in column 3, 4 and 5, to get this:

```
0;John Doe;2001;03;24;985392000
1;Jane Doe;1985;12;05;502588800
2;Mr. White;2018;06;01;1527811200
3;Jake White;2017;11;20;1511136000
...
```

So I wrote this *script.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
    printf "$line;"
    date -d $(awk -F\; '{print $3$4$5}' <<<$line) +%s
done
```

and I ran:

```
<list.csv ./script.sh
```

and it works, but it's very slow when it comes to having very large CSVs.

Is there a way to do it faster in a sed/awk command line?

I mean, can I (for instance) inject a bash command into a sed/awk line?
For example (I know this won't work, it's just an example):

```
awk -F\; '{print $1 ";" $2 ";" $3 ";" $4 ";" $5 ";" $(date -d $3$4$5 +%s)}'
```

Comment: This answer with `mktime` should put you in the right direction: [Convert date to epoch time using AWK in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965992/6176817).

Comment: And there seems to be a typo in your input: `2017:11;20`.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the typo and tried your tip. It works! It has only one problem: it returns the timestamp considering year/month/day of my timezone. I would like the UTC one. But this is a step forward! :-)

Comment: No... Wait! That's exactly what I want! Thank you!!!

Comment: Take a look at `utc-flag` in [`awk` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) if you want to play with timezones ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `awk` to the rescue!

```
$ gawk -F';' '{$0=$0 FS mktime($3" "$4" "$5" 00 00 00")}1' file

0;John Doe;2001;03;24;985410000
1;Jane Doe;1985;12;05;502606800
2;Mr. White;2018;06;01;1527825600
3;Jake White;2017;11;20;1511154000
```

not sure what hour/min/sec you use as default.

Answer (score 0):

For other awks without builtin time functions:

```
awk -F';' '{
    cmd = "date -d "$3 $4 $5" +%s"
    cmd | getline time
    close(cmd)
    $0 = $0 FS time
    print
}' file
```

or perl

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F';' -lane '
    print join ";", @F, Time::Piece->strptime("@F[2..4]", "%Y %m %d")->epoch
' file

# or
perl -MTime::Local -F';' -lane '
    print join ";", @F, timelocal(0, 0, 0, $F[4], $F[3]-1, $F[2]-1900)
' file
```