# Convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to seconds relative to 0

Tags: bash, shell, csv, time, text-processing

Have a csv file where line have 5 fields separated by comma:

```
2020-07-31 15:15:55,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:16:57,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:17:00,xx,yy,zz,t
```

and I would like to use the first line as 0 in seconds (relative time), so the output is like this:

```
0,xx,yy,zz,t
62,xx,yy,zz,t
65,xx,yy,zz,t
```

I can be done with any programming language, like bash, awk, sed, perl... and overwrite the same file or create a new one.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you want a pointer I'd start by searching for "awk date manipulation"

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "we'll do your work for you for free" site.
Show your effort, instead of asking for a ready solution. Show specific errors you need help with and example output that you expect.

Comment: @Smeterlink, could you please do let us know logic of getting expected output, sorry but its not clear to me.

Comment: Please show your attempt so that we know where you are stuck.

Comment: You should read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to acknowledge the effort of your answerers.

Comment: got a solution all ready to go and everything, lol ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer by @anubhava (there were only 2 fields):

You may use this `awk` with `mktime` function.
This will output the 2 fields separated by commas:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","                 # set input and output field separators to comma
}
{
   gsub(/[-:]/, " ", $1)      # replace - and : with a space
   tm = mktime($1)            # convert date-time string to EPOCH value
   if (NR == 1)               # for 1st records store this value in first
      first = tm
   print (tm - first), $2     # print difference and 2nd field for each record
}' file
```

Result:

```
0,xx
62,xx
65,xx
```

---

Improved by @smeterlink

This will detect all comma separated fields using the NF variable, so will work even if there's only the first field. That way lines of different number of fields can be mixed:

**get.awk**:

```
BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","                 # set input and output field separators to comma
}
{
   gsub(/[-:]/, " ", $1)      # replace - and : with a space
   tm = mktime($1)            # convert date-time string to EPOCH value
   if (NR == 1)               # for 1st records store this value in first
      first = tm
   {
      printf (tm - first)     # print difference
      if (NF > 1)             # print 2nd to last fields only if they exist
      {
         for (i = 2; i < NF; i += 1)
         printf ","$i
         print ","$NF
      }
      else
         print ""             # otherwise print newline after printf
   }
}
```

**file.csv**:

```
2020-07-31 15:15:55,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:16:57,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:17:00,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:17:23,xx,yy,zz,abc,009-%5
2020-07-31 15:18:00
2020-07-31 15:19:00,xx
```

**Result**:

```
awk -f get.awk file.csv
0,xx,yy,zz,t
62,xx,yy,zz,t
65,xx,yy,zz,t
88,xx,yy,zz,abc,009-%5
125
185,xx
```

Comment: You need to print until `$5`, here it is one-liner:
``awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/[-:]/, " ", $1); tm = mktime($1); if (NR == 1) first = tm; print (tm - first), $2, $3, $4, $5}' file.csv``

Comment: Thanks for your edit. My answer was based on your original question where you had only one value besides timestamp.

Comment: Expanded the post and kept your original answer as well added new one which will dynamically adjust to variable number of fields.

Comment: `mktime` is incompatible with `original-awk`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
perl -MTime::Piece -F, -lane '
    BEGIN {$, = ","}
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime(shift(@F), "%F %T")->epoch;
    if ($. == 1) {$start = $t}
    print $t - $start, @F;
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem that UNIX environment cannot handle easily.
Utilize [`teip`](https://github.com/greymd/teip).

```
$ teip -d, -f1 -- sh -c "date -f- +%s" < file.txt |
  awk -F, 'NR==1{n=$1}{$1=$1-n};4' OFS=,
0,xx,yy,zz,t
62,xx,yy,zz,t
65,xx,yy,zz,t
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer which works, considering that the day doesn't change, so it's omitted.

```
cat file.csv | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'| awk -F ':|,' '{printf ($1*3600+$2*60+$3)}{print ","$4","$5","$6","$7}'
```

This will output this result, which remains yet to rest the first value, which could be read from the file:

```
54955,xx,yy,zz,t
55017,xx,yy,zz,t
55020,xx,yy,zz,t
```

Now since the value is the same for all lines, it could be entered just manually:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'| awk -F ':|,' '{printf ($1*3600+$2*60+$3-54955)}{print ","$4","$5","$6","$7}'
```

which will give the desired result:

```
0,xx,yy,zz,t
62,xx,yy,zz,t
65,xx,yy,zz,t
```

***
Added later: thanks to this thread got a way to convert time to epoch, which is absolute:
[Convert date to epoch time using AWK in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965658/convert-date-to-epoch-time-using-awk-in-linux)
so it would remain something like this:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F, '{ OFS = FS;command="date -d " "\"" $1 "\""  " +%s";command | getline $1;close(command);print}'
1596201355,xx,yy,zz,t
1596201417,xx,yy,zz,t
1596201420,xx,yy,zz,t
```

**
Added later again:
The way to rest the first value is to use this awk expression:

```
| awk -F, 'NR==1{pattern=$1}{printf ($1-pattern)}{print ","$2","$3","$4","$5}'
```

So the 2 ways explained before will remain like this:
This case will only work is it's the same day:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'| awk -F ':|,' '{printf ($1*3600+$2*60+$3)}{print ","$4","$5","$6","$7}' | awk -F, 'NR==1{pattern=$1}{printf ($1-pattern)}{print ","$2","$3","$4","$5}'
```

And this (using epoch), will take into account the days:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F, '{ OFS = FS;command="date -d " "\"" $1 "\""  " +%s";command | getline $1;close(command);print}' | awk -F, 'NR==1{pattern=$1}{printf ($1-pattern)}{print ","$2","$3","$4","$5}'
```

---

**Best solution so far**: will take into account the days using epoch, and will work with any variant of awk, including BSD variants. Also it detects how many fields there are, and will work even if there's only the first one:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F, '{ OFS = FS;command="date -d " "\"" $1 "\""  " +%s";command | getline $1;close(command);print}' | awk -F, 'NR==1{pattern=$1}{printf ($1-pattern)}{if (NF > 1){for (i = 2; i < NF; i += 1) printf ","$i; print ","$NF} else print ""}'
```

**file.csv**:

```
2020-07-31 15:15:55,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:16:57,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:17:00,xx,yy,zz,t
2020-07-31 15:17:23,xx,yy,zz,abc,009-%5
2020-07-31 15:18:00
2020-07-31 15:19:00,xx
```

**Result**:

```
0,xx,yy,zz,t
62,xx,yy,zz,t
65,xx,yy,zz,t
88,xx,yy,zz,abc,009-%5
125
185,xx
```